# Go ThoughtWorks PATH on MAC for ant build

Tags: thoughtworks-go

I have created a pipeline in Go from ThoughtWorks that fails.  The error message is about not finding ant in the PATH.  I have defined an Environment where I override the PATH variable, but that does not seem to work.

Source code: https://github.com/aavella77/junit-sample.git

I can compile using ant from a terminal.  Not sure how to setup the PATH using Go.  Any suggestions?

```
[go] Start to prepare junit-sample-Pipeline/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on AAVELLA-M-G0AM [/Applications/Go Agent.app] at Sun Jan 25 22:13:16 PST 2015

[go] Start updating files at revision bae3528396b34f842ebe495fefd9f3a37dfb5f6d from https://github.com/aavella77/junit-sample.git
[GIT] Fetch and reset in working directory pipelines/junit-sample-Pipeline
[GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy
[GIT] Cleaning submodule configurations in .git/config
[GIT] Fetching changes
[GIT] Performing git gc
[GIT] Updating working copy to revision bae3528396b34f842ebe495fefd9f3a37dfb5f6d
HEAD is now at bae3528 Create build.xml
[GIT] Removing modified files in submodules
[GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy

[go] Start to build junit-sample-Pipeline/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on AAVELLA-M-G0AM [/Applications/Go Agent.app] at Sun Jan 25 22:13:17 PST 2015

[go] Current job status: passed.

[go] Start to execute task: <ant buildfile="build.xml" />. 
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_ENVIRONMENT_NAME' to value 'Production'
[go] overriding environment variable 'PATH' with value '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin/ant/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/bin/ant/bin'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_SERVER_URL' to value 'https://127.0.0.1:8154/go/'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_TRIGGER_USER' to value 'anonymous'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_NAME' to value 'junit-sample-Pipeline'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER' to value '25'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_LABEL' to value '25'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_NAME' to value 'defaultStage'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_COUNTER' to value '1'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_JOB_NAME' to value 'defaultJob'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_REVISION' to value 'bae3528396b34f842ebe495fefd9f3a37dfb5f6d'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_TO_REVISION' to value 'bae3528396b34f842ebe495fefd9f3a37dfb5f6d'
[go] setting environment variable 'GO_FROM_REVISION' to value 'bae3528396b34f842ebe495fefd9f3a37dfb5f6d'
[go] setting environment variable 'JUNIT_HOME' to value '/Library/JUNIT'
[go] setting environment variable 'CLASSPATH' to value '$CLASSPATH:/Library/JUNIT/junit-4.10.jar:.'
[go] setting environment variable 'ANT_HOME' to value '/usr/bin/ant/bin'
Error happened while attempting to execute 'ant -f build.xml'. 
Please make sure [ant] can be executed on this agent.

[Debug Information] Environment variable PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

[go] Start to create properties junit-sample-Pipeline/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on AAVELLA-M-G0AM [/Applications/Go Agent.app] at Sun Jan 25 22:13:18 PST 2015

[go] Start to upload junit-sample-Pipeline/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on AAVELLA-M-G0AM [/Applications/Go Agent.app] at Sun Jan 25 22:13:18 PST 2015

[go] Job completed junit-sample-Pipeline/25/defaultStage/1/defaultJob on AAVELLA-M-G0AM [/Applications/Go Agent.app] at Sun Jan 25 22:13:18 PST 2015
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with $PATH setting on agents for OSX. You can find details along with the solution logged here.

https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/852